# "String @NotNull []" syntax causes "'@NotNull' not applicable to type use" in intellij IDEA plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to fix a few bugs in an old, now open-sourced intellij IDEA plugin (the [CFML Plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/CFML))

The following Syntax appears several times in multiple files and generates an error:

```
String @NotNull []
```

This is what the error looks like:

[image]

The example is from the following file:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/master/CFML/src/com/intellij/coldFusion/model/CfmlUtil.java#L249

**What does this syntax do?**
I haven't found any information on it. It seems like `@NotNull String[]` would do exactly the same thing without the error.

**How do I get this to work?**
I have followed the setup instructions for [setting up a development environment](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/setting_up_environment.html) and [creating a plugin project](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/creating_plugin_project.html) exactly. What is my environment missing to run this code?

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/master/CFML/src/com/intellij/coldFusion/model/CfmlUtil.java#L249

I updated my answer to include the link

Comment: The file is unchanged, according to git.
How do I tell if I have the Annotations Library? Where do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you don't have the JetBrains Annotations library installed. Please follow the installation guide [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html).

The `String @NotNull []` syntax consists of the `@NotNull` annotation applied to the `String[]` *type*. Note that this is different from `@NotNull String[]`, in which `@NotNull` only applies to the `String` type. The annotation is used in this way to say that the string array returned will not be null, but the strings inside it might be.

Compare:

- `@NotNull String @Nullable []`: strings in the returned array must be non null, but a null array could be returned.
- `@NotNull String @NotNull []`: strings in the returned array must be non null, and the array must also be non null
- `@Nullable String @NotNull []`: The string array must be non null, but the strings inside it might be null
- `@Nullable String @Nullable []`: The string array could be null, and there might be null strings in it too

Comment: After installing the Annotations library and changing the order of the module dependencies the error went away (Project Structure -> Modules -> Plugin Module -> Dependencies -> annotations library to the top). Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

check your dependency ,may be you have include the validation-bean and validator-api,
they have the same package for `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`;

just exclude one of them ,and everythins is ok